# Configure remote rulesets with Puppet

Tags: puppet, prometheus, configuration-management, facter

I'm trying to automate the Prometheus `node_exporter` and my Prometheus Server. 
For the `node_exporter` I've written a module to install all the needed packages, set the `$::ipaddress` based on `facter` and some more..

Now I'd like to make sure that the collected informations (`$hostname`, `$job_name`, [...]) from the applying node are exported into the respective remote Prometheus configfile, but I want to have this step done asynchronously, so for example with a puppet agent run afterwards on the Prometheus Server.

I've tried to orientate the classes towards the `puppetlabs/logrotate` module, which is basically doing the following:

**logrotate/init.pp**

```
class logrotate (
  String $ensure              = present,
  Boolean $hieramerge         = false,
  Boolean $manage_cron_daily  = true,
  Boolean $create_base_rules  = true,
  Boolean $purge_configdir    = false,
  String $package             = 'logrotate',
  Hash $rules                 = {},
) {
  do some stuff
}
```

**logrotate/rules.pp**

```
class logrotate::rules ($rules = $::logrotate::rules){
  #assert_private()
  create_resources('logrotate::rule', $rules)
}
```

**logrotate/rule.pp**

```
define logrotate::rule(
  Pattern[/^[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+$/] $rulename           = $title,
  Enum['present','absent'] $ensure                  = 'present',
  Optional[Logrotate::Path] $path                   = undef,
  (...)
  ) {
    do some stuff
  }
```

Shortened my `ni_trending` (node_exporter) & `ni_prometheus` modules currently look very similar to `logrotate`:

**ni_trending/init.pp**

```
class ni_trending (
  $hostname       = $::fqdn,
  $listen_address = $::ipaddress,
  $listen_port    = 51118,
) { 

) inherits ni_trending::params {

anchor { 'ni_trending::start': }
  ->class { 'ni_trending::package': }
  ->class { 'ni_trending::config':
    (...)
    listen_address => $listen_address,
    listen_port    => $listen_port,
    (...)
    }
  ->class { 'ni_trending::service': }
  ->class { ' ni_trending::prometheus':
    (...)
    hostname     => $hostname,
    listen_port  => $listen_port,
    (...)
    }
    ->anchor { 'ni_trending::end': }
}
```

**ni_trending/prometheus.pp**

```
class ni_trending::prometheus (
  Hash $options        = {},
) {

  ni_prometheus::nodeexporterrule { 'node_exporter' :
    ensure      => pick_default($options['ensure'], 'present'),
    hostname    => pick_default($options['hostname'], $ni_trending::hostname),
    listen_port => pick_default($options['hostname'], $ni_trending::listen_port),
    }
}
```

**ni_prometheus/nodeexporterrules.pp**

```
class ni_prometheus::nodeexporterrules ($rules = $::ni_prometheus::nodeexporterrules) {

  create_resources('ni_prometheus::nodeexporterrule', $nodeexporterrules)

}
```

**ni_prometheus/nodeexporterrule.pp**

```
define ni_prometheus::nodeexporterrule (
  $job_name                         = $title,
  Enum['present','absent'] $ensure  = 'present',
  $hostname                         = $hostname,
  $listen_port                      = $listen_port,
) {

  file_line { "prometheus-${job_name}" :
    path  => "/etc/prometheus/${job_name}.list",
    after => 'hosts:',
    line  => "${hostname}:${listen_port}",
  }
}
```

But this will just work when I apply the `node_exporter` locally on the Prometheus Master - not in the case that an external machine has the `ni_trending::prometheus` class included, which makes sense to me - because it clearly feels that something is missing. :-) How can I get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite following what you want to do.  It may simply arise from unfamiliarity with Prometheus jargon.  How is "*I want to have this step done asynchronously, so for example with a puppet agent run afterwards on the Prometheus Server*" consistent with being dissatisfied that "*this will just work when I apply the `node_exporter` locally on the Prometheus Master*"?

Comment: Sorry - wording :-) Let's name the VM with the `ni_trending` (the actual `node_exporter`) applied "Publisher" and the Prometheus Server "Consumer".

I don't want the (Publisher) module `ni_trending` to do the actual change within the central Prometheus configuration file on the Prometheus Server (Consumer) - instead calling the `ni_prometheus::nodeexporterrule` class with variables to create a new entry in the config file - this `ni_prometheus` class is only applied on the Server (Consumer).

Comment: Another simplified usecase would be to setup a simple Icinga TCP Portcheck on a remote Icinga Server, when you deploy a certain service (Let's take Nginx as an example). In this case you already know all needed informations required to create a check on the serverside additionally to the check on the nginx node => The $::ipaddress out of facter and $http(s)_port out of the module or Hiera. For me it's just not clear how to do this properly.

Comment: Is the configuration file that you want to provide to the Consumer generated on the Publisher node itself?  Could it be (or is it already) generated on the Puppet master, on behalf of the Publisher?

Comment: No, I think that's an overhead because the configuration file on the Consumer does only need to hold the FQDNs & Ports of the publishers.
`dev01.invaliddomain.com:51181` - as an example.
I already get these two values (and work with them, e.g. modifying a `node_exporter-systemd-service` with environment variables) when I run the node_exporter (Publisher) Class and now would like to set them on the Server (Consumer) as well, by calling another module and class (ni_prometheus).

Comment: *Could it be (or is it already) generated on the Puppet master, on behalf of the Publisher?*

Sorry, I did not understand this sentence correctly. If you mean Puppet Master-generated like `content => template('ni_trending/node_exporter-systemd-service')` - then yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [exported resources](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_exported.html) (that makes [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53347866/how-can-a-puppet-resource-check-for-a-data-source-on-the-puppetmaster-without-fa) in one day!).  This is a facility for one node's catalog building to generate resources that can be applied to other nodes (and also, optionally, to the exporting node itself).  I'm still not tracking the details of what you want to manage where, so here's a more generic example: maintaining a local hosts file.

#### Generic example

Suppose we want to automatically manage a hosts file listing all our nodes under management.  Puppet has a built-in resource, [`Host`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/type.html#host), representing one entry in a hosts file.  We make use of that by having every node under management export an appropriate host resource.  Something like this would go inside a class included on every node:

```
@@host { "$hostname": ip => $ipaddress; }
```

The `@@` prefix marks the resource as exported.  It is not applied to the current target node, unless by the mechanism I will describe in a moment.  the `$hostname` and `$ipaddress` are just facts presented by the target node, and they are resolved in that context.  Note, too, that the resource title is globally unique: each target node has a different hostname, therefore all the exported `Host` resources that apply to different target nodes will have distinct titles.

Then, separately, every node that wants all those `Host` entries applied to it will *import* them in its own catalog by using an [exported resource collector](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_collectors.html):

```
<<|Host|>>
```

The nodes that export those resources can also collect some or all of them.  Additionally, there are ways to be more selective about which resources are collected; see the link above.

Comment: In general, exported resources always seem to be necessary when using Puppet to manage monitoring software, so unsurprising it fits Prometheus here. I think the example in the documentation is even for Nagios.

Comment: Yeees, thanks! Already looked into the documentation, matches my requirement!